# Why I am getting this error "rows inserted or updated at the subscriber cannot be outside the article partition"?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication, transactional-replication, subscriber

When I insert rows at the subscriber end I get following error

`rows inserted or updated at the subscriber cannot be outside the article partition`

Why I am getting this error? How to resolve it.

Comment: What type of replication are you using?

Comment: I'm using transactional replication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when article filtering is being used and an inserted row is outside the Subscriber's partition.  When using filtering, you must ensure that inserts and updates at the Subscriber do not result in rows that fall outside the partition of the Subscriber.

Check your article filtering criteria and adjust your application logic accordingly so that inserted rows are inside a given Subscriber's partition.